# Jsoup selector - How to select the first 5 <p> elements inside <div> element

Tags: java, jsoup

There is a bunch of html elements as following:

```
<div class="abcdefghijk">
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <p>c</p>
   <p>d</p>
   <p>e</p>
   <p>f</p>
   <p>h</p>
   <p>i</p>
   <p>j</p>
   <p>k</p>
</div>
```

I want to select the first 5 `<p>` elements. 
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all of them anyway, but do something special with the first 5, use [`Elements#subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) (inherited from `ArrayList`):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive.

```
String html = 
    "<div class=\"abcdefghijk\">" +
        "<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p><p>d</p><p>e</p>" + // get these
        "<p>f</p><p>h</p><p>i</p><p>j</p><p>k</p>" +
    "</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements paras = doc.select("div.abcdefghijk p");
for (Element el : paras.subList(0, Math.min(5, paras.size())) {
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Output:

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>e</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

From https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax we can learn about:

> `:lt(n)` : find elements whose sibling index (i.e. its position in the DOM tree relative to its parent) is less than `n`; e.g. `td:lt(3)`

So based on your example all you need is `select("div.abcdefghijk p:lt(5)")`.

Demo:

```
String html = " <div class=\"abcdefghijk\">\r\n" + 
        "   <p>a</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>b</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>c</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>d</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>e</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>f</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>h</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>i</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>j</p>\r\n" + 
        "   <p>k</p>\r\n" + 
        "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("div.abcdefghijk p:lt(5)");
for (Element el : elements){
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Output:

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>e</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result , use nth child selector

```
:nth-child(-n+5)
select("div.abcdefghijk :nth-child(-n+5)")
```

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html